# Content extracted from API call gives 0 value

Tags: php, mysql, json, api, pdo

The content extracted with

```
<?php
$item = $_GET['item'];
$item = str_replace("\"", "", $item);
$item = str_replace("\'", "", $item);
$item = str_replace(" ", "%20", $item);
$item = str_replace("\\", "", $item);
@include_once ("pdocon.php");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name=?");
$stmt->execute(array($item));
$rs = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmtt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT auth FROM auth where id=1");
$stmtt->execute(); 
$code = $stmtt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//print_r($code);
if(!empty($rs)) {
        if(time()-$rs["lastupdate"] < 604800) die($rs["cost"]);
}
$url = "?api_key=(mykeyhere)&code=".$code."&names=".$item."&delimiter=!END!";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$obj = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if($obj->{'status'} == "fail") die("notfound");
$lowest_price = $obj->data->prices[0]->price;
$lowest_price = (float)($lowest_price);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE items SET `cost` = ?,`lastupdate` = ? WHERE `name` = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($lowest_price, time(), $item));
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO items (`name`,`cost`,`lastupdate`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array($item, $lowest_price, time()));
echo $lowest_price;
?>
```

gives 0 value in database. Anyone know why? The above code should show the result of the "price" which is "1300.00", not 0.
API call should provide the values in the picture: https://gyazo.com/a514f7f46e976d43efd008de778cb5c5
Or code:

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "prices" : [
      {
        "market_hash_name" : "AWP | Dragon Lore (Minimal Wear)",
        "price" : "1300.00"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume that you are talking about this line of code: `$lowest_price = $obj->data->prices[0]->price;` Where did you use `json_decode()` to actually **generate** the `$obj` ?

Comment: json_decode() wasn't working before so I had to do cURL

Comment: I have no idea why it didn't work but I used: $string = file_get_contents($link);
$json = $string;

$obj = json_decode($json);

Comment: No, no, there is kind of a misunderstanding, you will need to use both, see my answer below.

Comment: side note: never use `@include_once()` . Use `require_once()` to include file is better, as it generate errors and stop the script to run. Also, not to suppress error / warning with `@` during debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment, you need to parse the curl output with json_decode():

```
$obj = json_decode(curl_exec($curl)); // json_decode gives back an object
curl_close($curl);
if($obj->{'status'} == "fail") die("notfound");
```

Comment: Can you include your result from `echo print_r($obj);` in your answer? Simply edit it.

Comment: stdClass Object ( [status] => success [data] => stdClass Object ( [error_message] => API access enabled, but unable to verify two-factor authentication code. If you need help with this, please contact support@bitskins.com. ) ) 10 showed right now... and after I reload I get 0

Comment: I'm running it here: http://lockthepot.com/costinitial.php?item=AWP%20|%20Dragon%20Lore%20(Minimal%20Wear)

Comment: But you did read the error message, didn't you? There is a problem with your authentication and there is no price field included in your response!

Comment: But if I enable the print_r($code) it's showing the generated code like this:  "Array ( [auth] => 510280 ) 0" where 0 is the price...

Comment: Also getting this if I manually input outdated auth code in manual browser api call: https://gyazo.com/d0d25decfa47367beb62a88db0527d3e

Comment: Oh wait if it displays like Array ( [auth] => 510280 ) when I do print then will it display like that withing the link too? Thus leading to this error?

Comment: I tried to input in the url the code manually and I got the right price! I think the code is imported as array ([auth]=> 510280) instead of the actual number. How can I fix that? https://gyazo.com/9f4264821bcd7da11ab7cbc20cf80e3d

Comment: Nvm I fixed it .. I didn't realize I needed [auth] in the link